# Populating a Node v8 Float32Array from C++

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I've looked into the documentation:

- [Float32Array](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-5.0/d6/d78/classv8_1_1_float32_array.html)
- [ArrayBuffer](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-5.0/d5/d6e/classv8_1_1_array_buffer.html)
- [Array](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-5.0/d3/d32/classv8_1_1_array.html)

I am trying to populate a v8 array of floats, using a `thrust::host_vectofr<float>`, where `dataset[i].vector = thrust::host_vector<float>`

Using an Array, seems to be rounding to integers:

```
Local<Object> obj = Object::New(isolate);
Local<Array> vec = Array::New(isolate, dataset[i].vector.size());

// populate the v8 array (copy)
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < dataset[i].vector.size(); k++)
    vec->Set(k, Number::New(isolate, dataset[i].vector[k]));

obj->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "vector"), vec);
```

Using a *typed* array, the `Float32Array`:

```
Local<Object> obj = Object::New(isolate);
auto vec = Float32Array::New(ArrayBuffer::New(isolate, sizeof(float)), 0, dataset[i].vector.size());

// populate the v8 array (copy)
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < dataset[i].vector.size(); k++)
    vec->Set(k, Number::New(isolate, dataset[i].vector[k]));

obj->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "vector"), vec);
```

Compiles fine, but when executing it crashes:

```
*** Error in `node': corrupted double-linked list: 0x000000000734bf50 ***
fish: “node run.js” terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

What is the *correct* approach to allocating and then populating a v8 Float32Array from C++, so that it can be used in JavaScript?

I also understand that Node.JS/v8 does not come with a `float`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of V8 that is (calling Set without a context isn't in the API docs I see), but on 4.10, this works fine:

```
auto arr = v8::Array::New(isolate);
(void)arr->Set(context, 0, v8::Number::New(isolate, 2.5));
auto number = arr->Get(context, 0);
printf("%s\n", *v8::String::Utf8Value(number.ToLocalChecked()));
```

prints out

```
2.5
```

Converting it to a floating point value also works:

```
printf("%f\n", ((v8::Number*)*number.ToLocalChecked())->Value());
```

Comment: Whats `context` in this case? I'm using node 5.4.0

Comment: I don't know anything about node.   context is a v8::Context object.  The call I'm using is the second from the top here: http://v8.paulfryzel.com/docs/master/classv8_1_1_object.html

Comment: The first three urls I've posted. This `context` seems to be a local reference to global memory. Thanks for your reply, I'll try and make some sense out of it.

Comment: if you look for the Object docs on the same URL as what you've posted, I don't see any version of Set that matches your syntax.  Can you find it?

Comment: In other words, what API call is this: vec->Set(k, Number::New(isolate, dataset[i].vector[k]));  ?  I don't see docs for it.

Comment: I'm starting to think this is not a v8 issue, but my algorithm's problem. I used as my guide: http://blog.scottfrees.com/c-processing-from-node-js-part-3-arrays which compiles and works, problem is I only get 0 and 1. But I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: that seems more likely than v8 not understanding floating point values, as that's the core numeric type of javascript.

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: no worries.  Also, I just tried ->Set without the context in my code and it worked (still got floating point value back).   I have no idea where that call is in the docs, as it is nice to not have to give the context every time.

Comment: Oh, I see it.  It's in a DEPRECATE_SOON block, which is why it's not documented.    V8_DEPRECATE_SOON("Use maybe version",
                    bool Set(uint32_t index, Local<Value> value));

Comment: it makes sense, its constantly evolving its getting hard to keep track. In any case, the issue is definitely with my code elsewhere, so the code above is fine :-)